# How to write SQL Query to get number of the longest series of greater than zero values in row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
|  id   | prize |
-----------------
|   1   |   8   |
|   2   |   2   |
|   3   |   5   |
|   4   |   0   |
|   5   |   0   |
|   6   |   2   |
|   7   |   0   |
|   8   |   1   |
|   9   |   4   |
```

And here as you can see the longest series of positive values is 3 (8,2,5)

I want to get result like this:

```
| result |
----------
|   3    |
```

I could check this in php but it is important to me to do it in one SQL Query.

Edit: By positive I meant greater than zero.

Comment: All those values are positive, I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: I meant greater than zero.

Comment: i set them id before, sorry i will edit this now to see it clearer

Comment: Is `3` in your result the number of items in the series, or the id of the last record that is in the series?

Comment: 3 is the number of items in the series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this solution:

```
select max(t.sequenceCnt)
from
(
    select t.cnt, count(*) sequenceCnt
    from
    (
        select d1.id, count(d2.id) cnt
        from data d1
        left join data d2 on d1.id < d2.id and d2.price = 0
        where d1.price != 0
        group by d1.id
    ) t
    group by t.cnt
) t
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=557f180d44c50f57ae56546613fc416d)

The core of this solution is the innermost subquery:

```
select d1.id, count(d2.id) cnt
from data d1
left join data d2 on d1.id < d2.id and d2.price = 0
where d1.price != 0
group by d1.id
```

where consecutive nonzero prices have [the same](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8ea6ad3781e7a606664e3ab5854ad4ca) `cnt` value. Once you have this the rest is easy. You group according to the `cnt` and then find the max.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I see that on your fiddle it is working, but what i shoud put in "data" place?

Comment: "data" is your table name.

Comment: But if it is not a table but a result from other query?

Comment: Put that entire query and give appropriate aliases to columns.